# jQuery hover Issue with div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show/hide certain data on mouse hover over a div tag.

My html:

```
 <div id='container'>
                        <div id="box" style="visibility: hidden">
                            <a href="#" class="bt btleft">Highlight it</a>
                            <a href="#" class="bt btright">Reset</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My jquery:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#container").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).children("div").show(100);
            },
            function () {
                $(this).children("div").hide(100);
            });​
    });

</script>
```

But, hover doesn't do anything!! Please suggest the way around.

Comment: You have an invisible byte order mark after the last closing, which is a syntax error.

Comment: And `show` doesn't show elements that are already visible, and your elements are by the jQuery definition visible as they take up space.

Comment: Can you please tell what is that mark you specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.show()` and `.hide()` toggle the `display` property, not `visibility`. If you want to animate visibility, you could animate the `opacity` CSS property:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).children('div').animate({'opacity':'1'},100);
    },
    function() {
      $(this).children('div').animate({'opacity':'0'},100);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'>
  <div id="box" style="opacity: 0">
    <a href="#" class="bt btleft">Highlight it</a>
    <a href="#" class="bt btright">Reset</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.  It works,  But i have got another problem; I have this repeated in each row.  But, the show/hide works only for the first row

Comment: You'll need to select a common class for each row, like `$('.container')`. IDs need to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

`Visibility` will not work for you. Try this [JSfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/wpjkh4a3/)

`show` and `hide` will only work for `display` properties.

You should not have inline styles in your html.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#container").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).children("div").css('visibility', 'visible');
            },
            function () {
                $(this).children("div").css('visibility', 'hidden');
            });
    });
```